# Create background process and get process ID

Tags: php, multithreading, background-process, kill

OK, so here's what I want...

I'm triggering the **background execution** of a php script like this :

```
/usr/bin/php myscript.php > /dev/null &
```

The script runs for some time, and stops when finished.

However, I'd really need to have its process id (PID) so that I could **kill the process** (if needed) by :

```
kill -SIGTERM PID
```

However, how do I get the **PID** of that particular process?

---

**NOTE:** There may be numerous `php` processes at any time, so targetting all instances running is not what we need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the PID of your background process at the time you start it.

- `$$` is the current script's pid
- `$!` is the pid of the last background process

For instance :

```
/usr/bin/php myscript.php > /dev/null &
LAST_PID=$!
kill $LAST_PID
```

Comment: Awesome answer (waiting to accept it...)! Thanks a lot, mate! You've saved me so much time! :-)

Comment: You are welcome! I was looking for the exact same thing last year. :-D